# Is it possible to use a pixel shader inside a sprite?

Tags: directx, effects, shader, sprite

Is it possible to use a pixel shader inside a sprite?

I have create a simple pixel shader, that just writes red color, for
testing.
I have surrounded my Sprite.DrawImage(tex,...) call by the
effect.Begin(...), BeginPass(0), and EndPass(), End(),
but my shader seems not to be used : My texture is drawn just
normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what language you are using. I will assume this is an XNA question.

> *Is it possible to use a pixel shader
>   inside a sprite?*

Yes, you can load a shader file (HLSL, up to and including shader model 3 in XNA) and call spritebatch with using it.

If you post sample code it would be easier for us to see if anything isn't setup properly. However, It looks like you have things in the right order. I would check the shader code.

Your application code should look something like this:

```
Effect effect; 
effect = Content.Load<Effect> ("customeffect"); //load "customeffect.fx"
effect.CurrentTechnique = effect.Techniques["customtechnique"];

effect.Begin();

foreach (EffectPass pass in effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
 {
     pass.Begin();

     spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteBlendMode.AlphaBlend, SpriteSortMode.Immediate, SaveStateMode.None);

     spriteBatch.Draw(texture, Vector2.Zero, null, Color.White, 0, new Vector2(20, 20), 1, SpriteEffects.None, 0);

     spriteBatch.End();

     pass.End();
 }

 effect.End();
```

Comment: Thanx for your reply,but i am using Managed DirectX, so it is possible to use in MDX?

Comment: Yes, don't see any reason it shouldn't. Why not just try it?